# Print a variable from an external lib

Tags: python

I have an external lib. Let's call it ExtarnalLib. This lib contains a method, let's call it method_from_lib. This method take a variable which name is uri. My own code doesn't call the ExternalLib, because it's a code used, from a lib inside a lib and another liber etc....

I would like to print the uri variable.

Would this be possible in python ? If yes how.

I have an intuition it would be possible because with flexmock you can check if a specific function from a specific module is called with some specific args.

Something like :

```
flexmock(distantLibModuleName.Nameclass).should_receive('methodName').with_args(the_args)
```

But in my I'm not testing, I'm debugging a code. Normally I would simply follow the stack execution with pdb, but I can't because I only have this problem in prod and I don't have access to a shell.

Comment: So you mean that at some point in your code, you want to descend the stack and look at the value of that argument that eventually led to your code being called?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. I know how to do with pdb bug in my case I don't have  access to a shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but I have found that `inspect.stack` should do what you want.

Sample directory structure:

`a.py`

```
from b import another_function

def inspect_me(inspect_this):
    another_function()

inspect_me(inspect_this='hello')
```

`b.py`

```
from c import what_was_it

def another_function():
    what_was_it()
```

`c.py`

```
import inspect

result = None

def what_was_it():
    global result
    result = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())
```

From the shell:

```
import a
import c
import os

[frame_data.code_context for frame_data in c.result if os.path.basename(frame_data.filename) == 'a.py']
```

Output:

```
[['    another_function()\n'], 
 ["inspect_me(inspect_this='hello')\n"]]
```

You can then visually inspect the output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have `mod.py` where:

```
def x(uri):
    print("URI", uri)
```

And then `mod2.py` which calls the `mod.py:x` function:

```
import mod

def y():
    print("Y")
    mod.x(123)
```

And if we wrap it in our main script:

```
import mod
import mod2

def wrap(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("PRE", *args, **kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("POST")

    return wrapper

mod.x = wrap(mod.x)

mod2.y()
```

Calling the `mod2.py:y` will yield:

```
Y
PRE 123
URI 123
POST
```